# Selenium Proxy Settings

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I need to use Selenium via proxy in Python. My  private proxy type is: `user:password:ip:port`. The code below works, but it doesn't have the `user` and `password` options. Is there anyone who can update this code? Thanks.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


"Define Both ProxyHost and ProxyPort as String"
ProxyHost = "ip"
ProxyPort = "port"



def ChangeProxy(ProxyHost ,ProxyPort):
    "Define Firefox Profile with you ProxyHost and ProxyPort"
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", ProxyHost )
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", int(ProxyPort))
    profile.update_preferences()
    return webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)


def FixProxy():
    "Reset Firefox Profile"
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 0)
    return webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)


driver = ChangeProxy(ProxyHost ,ProxyPort)
driver.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")

time.sleep(5)

driver = FixProxy()
driver.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

**Define your attribute:**

```
    username = "your_username_here" 
    password = "your_password_here"
```

Then add these to your preferences :

```
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_username", username)
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_password", password)
```

**Another approach :**

```
profile.set_preference('network.http.phishy-userpass-length', 255)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("https://username:password@somewebsite.com:port/")
```